# Проверка на наличие параметра в URL через jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу сделать проверку на наличие параметров в URL, чтобы выполнять действие только при их наличии. Сами параметры получаю вот так.

```js
$.urlParam = function(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  return results[1] || 0;
}

$.urlParam('param1');
$.urlParam('id');
$.urlParam('param2');
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Ныа

```js
const getParam=(name, url=window.location.href)=>{
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    const results = new RegExp(`[?&]${name}(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)`).exec(url);
    if(!results || !results[2])return false;
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```